# Finding multiple keywords in an input in Batch

Tags: batch-file, find

What I am trying to do is to create a program that can recognises when multiple phrases are in an input.

The code I am using is this:

```
:loop
set /p input="> "
echo %input%|find /i "Hello" >nul && echo Good Morning 
echo %input%|find /i "hi" >nul && echo Hello.
echo %input%|find /i "who are you" >nul && echo I am Dell, %name%. if you want help, ask.
echo %input%|find /i "your name" >nul && echo My name is Dell. What's yours? 
echo %input%|find /i "my name is" >nul && echo That's a nice name.
echo %input%|find /i "I am " >nul && echo Well, I like your name.
echo %input%|find /i "weather" >nul && echo Wonderful. Sun is shining.
echo %input%|find /i "help" >nul && echo Type your phrases in full sentences, like: NO i do not have a Job, rather than 'no'. Sometimes I struggle to understand...
echo %input%|find /i "bye" >nul && (echo what a pity. See you! & goto :eof)
echo %input%|find /i "nothing" >nul && (echo I see, well sorry! & goto :loop)
echo %input%|find /i "Home" >nul && (echo What is bothering you about home? & goto :1)
echo %input%|find /i "School" >nul && (echo What is bothering you about school? & goto :1)
echo %input%|find /i "College" >nul && (echo what is bothering you about College? & goto :1)
echo %input%|find /i "game" >nul && echo When you say game, do you mean a Video game?
echo %input%|find /i "Job" >nul && echo %name%, do you have a job?
echo %input%|find /i "fuck" >nul && echo Please do not swear
REM choose your keywords wisely...
goto :loop
```

I want the program to put two and two together like, it asks "do you have a Job", and if you replied "No, I don't have a job", it could pick out "don't" and "Job", or "no" and "Job" so it can recognise this to say something based on what it has found.
This could help, as I would like the computer to also recognise "Yes, I do have a Job"

Is it possible to so this?

Methods I have tried:

```
echo %input%|find /i "don't" "Job" >nul && echo Good Morning 
echo %input%|find /i "don't" & "Job" >nul && echo Good Morning 
echo %input%|find /i "don't & Job" >nul && echo Good Morning 
echo %input%|find /i "don't Job" >nul && echo Good Morning
```

Comment: `cmd` is a terrible language; you can do what you want with `findstr` using its (limited, hokey) support for regular expressions, but I would seriously suggest you look for a less insane environment for learning about these things.

Comment: Like what? What code program do you suggest? Preferably, something like batch, since I am also working on a game, using batch, with music inside of the Batch profile!        The Music Works as well!

Comment: Python is popular these days, and should be fairly easy to get into slowly, just familiarizing yourself with the string handling features. But if you _like_ Windows, you are nothing like me, so maybe take my advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: I will certainly consider practicing a bit of python xD! That will be something I may try when I get more better!

Comment: What happens If I reply `no`, `no, I have no job`, or `unfortunately I am jobless`, or even `no I do not have a job`, none of those contain the string `don't` and will all fail the test! There are too many possible responses to every question, you are completely wasting your time, if you think you can make 'some sort of AI' using these methods.

Comment: Thats why I also wanted to have a second line which will find any negative words and the main category word and put them together. This is practically a draft program example I am using to create a Game which uses inputs, and registers the user input and responds accordingly. The best example I can think of is of the game here: https://msmemorial.if-legends.org/games.htm/fish.php

Comment: Apart from all of that, what happens if I insert poison characters in my response, either deliberately or by typo. `I work at B & J`, `I am only 5' 2" and it sucks`

Comment: It would close the program down. I am not sure if special character s can be used... unless... I have a method of displaying specific colors in a batch file, ILl link the post

Comment: The issue is that `set /p` doesn't stop the end user from entering nothing at all, or any combination of characters they wish. So you're already basing your almost impossible system on a not very good input mechanism. You could enable delayed expansion, then use `echo !input!`, but depending upon your implementation, that could delete or prevent the use of `!` characters. _(and I know how much questioners, and answerers, love to exclaim everything!)_

Comment: True. Here is what I did for the color. Thing. The link will be posted when the 90 mins limit is up: call :c f0 "I like to shop at B & Q" /n

Answer (score -2):

Also an update:
This code line works, kind of....

```
echo %input% |findstr /i "\<No\> \<Job\>" >nul && echo TEXT HERE!
```

The problem is that it will echo TEXT HERE!! if you enter "no" or "job", rather than with both. I only want the "TEXT HERE!!" to show if both are present

Comment: A simple regular expression to check for "no" and "job" in any order is `no.*job|job.*no`. If `findstr` supports word boundaries like `\b` or `\<...\>` maybe add those, to avoid "no" matching "gnome" or "canonical", and "jobs" matching "jojoba" or "conjobble".

Comment: I just added a space on either side of the word: " no " and " job ". But Thank you! I am going to test it out

Comment: That will fail if "no" or "job" is adjacent to beginning/end of string. You really want to explore what regular expressions can do for you.

Comment: Good point. How would this string do `echo %input%|find /i "No" >nul && echo %input%|find /i "Job" >nul && echo TEXT HERE!!` This seems to work at the moment. Whether or not it is flawless, I so not know. Correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Please remember my initial comment, a completely reasonable answer to the question was `unfortunately I am jobless`. This does not include the word `no`, or the string `no`, and does not include the word `job`, only the string `job`, or perhaps, for the purposes of the above example `\<job`. The only way for this type of interaction, using basic batch file scripting and tools to work, is if you allow the end user to only provide answers from a known set of reponses. For that you'd itemize the responses to each question, and allow them to press a specific key, to select their chosen response.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your amendments into the question by pressing `Edit`in the line `Share Edit Follow Close Flag` at the bottom of the original post. This makes sure that all relevant information is present in one location - responses attempting to solve the problem are likely to separate these amendments from the original posting, for instance.
`